# How to print plural acronym for the first time?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I have been making many attempts trying to fix this but still cannot work.

What I want is to have an acronym called `SBM` with its long form being State-Based Model. And when I call `\glspl{SBM}` for the first time in the report it can show me this:

```
State-Based Models (SBMs)
```

And it will show "SBMs" for the second time I call `\glspl{SBM}`

I tried using the following definition for the acronym but it does not work:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\begin{document}
\newacronym[plural=SBMs,longplural={State-Based Models}]{SBM}{SBM}{State-Based Model}
\glspl{SBM}
\glspl{SBM}
\end{document}
```

My compilation order (I use this order for all the singular form of acronyms and they work) is

1. pdflatex report.tex
2. makeindex -s report.ist -t report.glg -o report.gls report.glo
3. makeglossaries report
4. pdflatex report.tex

Comment: Welcome! Please post a complete, small document demonstrating the issue. We want something we can copy-paste-compile to see what you're seeing.

Comment: I have edited it. Basically I hope my two calls on glspl can yield the similar results as call on \gls command. @cfr

Comment: I have no problems with your code. It does what you want. BTW: you forgot to add `\makeglossaries` to generate the glossary.

Comment: I recommend you move `\newacronym` to the preamble (put it before `\begin{document}`). Can you clarify what result you actually want compared to the result you're actually getting.

Comment: By the way, that's an abbreviation, not an acronym.  Or more precisely: an initialism.